# Refactoring code to move code inside function results in undefined error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to restructure some code. Right now it looks like this:

```
async function myfunction(ref) {
  var r1 = await getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page");
  var r2 = await getReport(r1.reportID, "get").then(r2 => reportHandler(r1.reportID, r2, 0));
  return r2;
}

const data= await myFunction(ref);
if(data!=null && data.report.data!=null){
  const result = data.report.data.reduce((r, e) => {
    e.breakdownTotal.forEach(el => {
      let key = "data";
      if(!r[key]) r[key] = []
      r[key].push(...el.counts)
    })
    return r;
  }, {})
}
```

However, I want to restructure it to be in a single function like this:

```
async function myfunction(ref) {
  var r1 = await getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page");
  var r2 = await getReport(r1.reportID, "get").then(r2 => reportHandler(r1.reportID, r2, 0));
  if(r2!=null && r2.report.data!=null) {
    const result = r2.report.data.reduce((r, e) => {
      e.breakdownTotal.forEach(el => {
        let key = "data";
        if(!r[key]) r[key] = []
        r[key].push(...el.counts)
      })
      return r;
    }, {})
  }
}
```

However I've not had any luck getting this to work. In this particular case I get this error:

> mytest3.html:10 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'data' of undefined
>       at myfunction (mytest3.html:10)

Reporthandler code:

```
async function reportHandler(id, r2, retries) {
  if (retries >= 3 || r2.error != "report_not_ready") return r2;
  await sleep(2000);
  var report = await getReport(id, "get");
  return reportHandler(id, report, retries + 1);
}
```

Comment: well you really only check if data is not null, undefined would be a valid option

Comment: I think `reportHandler` has some issue as the response of `r2` is `undefined`.

Comment: Please include the code for `reportHander`, it looks like it's returning `undefined`.

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech Added that in

Comment: Your `reportHandler` is returning `undefined`. What else do you want to know here?